# is it possible to get page description in window overlay mode in compiz?

Tags: compiz

I am a fan of the window overlay mode of Gnome 3 because I can see the icon of the application in the overlay mode and also the description of the window. it helps me choose faster. is it possible to get the same functionality in Unity with compiz?

For a better explanation, here is a screenhot of Gnome 3 with icon overlay

[image: Gnome 3 with window overlay, text and icons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer. Starting from Ubuntu 12.10, there is a new feature called Unity Spread, which kind of gives something similar, with page description on the top.

> Moving the pointer over a preview displays the window title in the
>   titlebar and also, a close button is available so you can close the
>   window directly from the spread:

via [WebUpd8: Unity Spread](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/new-unity-spread-design-for-ubuntu-1210.html)